# Spring Cloud Eureka Server self preservation and renew threshold

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

(It is basically two Eureka server and three Eureka client microservices)

I want to remove the following message:

> EMERGENCY! EUREKA MAY BE INCORRECTLY CLAIMING INSTANCES ARE UP WHEN THEY'RE NOT. RENEWALS ARE LESSER THAN THRESHOLD AND HENCE THE INSTANCES ARE NOT BEING EXPIRED JUST TO BE SAFE.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK1Wx.png)

Eureka Server1:

```
spring.application.name=ms-service-discovery-1
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation= true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=1
eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 1000
eureka.server.responseCacheUpdateIntervalMs: 1000
```

Eureka Server2:

```
spring.application.name=ms-service-discovery-2
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.enableSelfPreservation= true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=1
eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000
eureka.server.wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 1000
```

Comment: Do you get that message when starting up eureka? It takes a while for the applications to get properly stablished, so it might be normal behaviour. Also have you tried with default interval values?

Comment: the server is up more than 10 hours and the message continues, it appeared a little after I uploaded the server, when I stopped one of the client micro services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to Eureka's self-preservation mode. Eureka servers will stop the eviction of all instances if the number of heartbeats renewals is below the expected threshold. The warning in your Eureka servers shows this situation happened.

Please try to adjust the below property. 85% is the default value. First, just try to lower the below property like `0.50`

```
eureka.renewalPercentThreshold=0.85
```

Alternatively, you can disable self-preservation mode with the below property.

```
eureka.enableSelfPreservation=false
```

**Note**
Basically, all Eureka client unregister itself when it shuts down. If it unregisters itself successfully, the above problem will not happen.

Unfortunately, sometimes the Spring Cloud based Eureka client doesn't unregister itself when it shuts down and the symptom is different based on the Spring Cloud version. Dalston and Edgware release unregister itself well in most cases. But Finchley releases seem not to unregister itself now.

Also, you start to run MANY instances in your Eureka environment, the above message will disappear because just one or two instances shutdown will not reach the threshold.

You can find more information about self-preservation mode [here](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Server-Self-Preservation-Mode)